# How to structure tables that each contain unique but also share common fields?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-schema, entity-relationship

Say you have several tables that contain unique properties but also share common properties, what is the best way to structure the tables for both performance and best practices? Assume there could be millions of records.

Please see below for a better visual of what I'm talking about.

[Option 1: Break out into one-to-one relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zb18.png)

[Option 2: Have shared props in each of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcXDB.png)

Comment: This is likely to be considered a an opinion question therefore likely to be closed. Ask yourself "Will your application(s) have independent processes on the common attributes/" If so then option 1 is clearly (IMO) the better choice. Even if not I would lean toward the option, but **always** subject to what processing the data must support. There is another option. Postgres supports "[table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html)". I personally avoid as it has issues but you should be aware of the option.

Comment: In postgresql specifically, an advantage to option 2 is that you could have a [parent table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) with all the shared columns, and even query across all question types by querying the parent table (though OC you'll be limited to the columns that are in the parent). I've found this to be a useful approach for keeping the physical tables separate - so they can have different indices, etc based on the type - while still permitting easy reporting over the entire dataset by querying the parent.

Comment: The processing will need to process the shared and unique props into a formula based on the question type. Essentially, I will need to join all the question types based on test_id and join again on a question_type_answer table (each question will have an answer), then process all the data, and return an aggregation of the results. Inheritance looks very promising, but still concerned about performance issues.